# LaTeX doesn't like my \hspace

Tags: spacing

Using TeXShop, I get complaints when LaTeXing the following code:

```
\beq
\mathrm{Cosmic\; ray\; } p + \mathrm{Nucleus}   \longrightarrow  \pi + \dots  
\eeq
\vspace{-.30 cm}
\hspace{6.05 cm}   $ \decayarrow} \mu + \num$
\newline 
\hspace*{6.95 cm}   $ \decayarrow} e + \nue + \num$

The command \decayarrow is defined in the preamble as:
\def\decayarrow{\kern0.2em\hbox{$\raise1.08ex\hbox{\big|}\kern-0.5em
                \longrightarrow$}\,}
```

Here is the relevant part of the console log (I hit Return after the ?):

```
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
l.43 \hspace{6.05 cm}   $ \decayarrow}
                                       \mu + \num$
? 
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
l.45 \hspace*{6.95 cm}   $ \decayarrow}
                                        e + \nue + \num$
? 
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2009/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
```

The resulting pdf looks OK, and I can't find any unbalanced $ or curly brackets. If I comment out the two lines beginning with \vspace, there's no problem; commenting out one of the \hspace lines means I only have to hit Return once to complete texing. So, it's an \hspace problem, but what?

I'm using a very old Mac Powerbook, running 10.5.8 (the latest it can run), with TeXShop v2.43 (I don't know if a newer version will help, or even if it can run; likewise, I haven't updated my TeX installation for many years on this device).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You should not use that much `\hspace` and `\vspace` commands at all, they destroy the typographic layout in my point of view

Answer (score 6):

As clearly shown in your error message

```
 $ \decayarrow} \mu + \num$
```

You have  a `}` with no `{` in that math expression.

The markup is hmm strange, you really shouldn't have any `\hspace` or `\newline` within the document markup. Hard to say from a fragment but this should presumably be using `align`.

in addition

```
 \hbox{\big|}\
```

from the definition you show will also generate errors as `\big` is a math mode command and the contents of `\hbox` are set in text mode.